# ¿Cómo obtener el listado de videos de un CDN con PHP?

Tags: php, html

Quiero obtener la `URL` y la calidad de los vídeos de [**esta dirección**](https://player.vimeo.com/video/248179269/config?autopause=1&byline=0&collections=1&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CClipController.main&default_to_hd=1&outro=nothing&portrait=0&share=1&title=0&watch_trailer=0&s=fcf097765e5857464f33a60d7466087fe8104def_1514060835) usando `PHP`

Ejemplo PHP :

```
 parse_str(file_get_contents('https://player.vimeo.com/video/248179269/config?autopause=1&byline=0&collections=1&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CClipController.main&default_to_hd=1&outro=nothing&portrait=0&share=1&title=0&watch_trailer=0&s=fcf097765e5857464f33a60d7466087fe8104def_1514060835'), $video_data);
   $streams = $video_data['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];

$streams = explode(',',$streams);


    foreach ($streams as $streamdata) {   
      parse_str($streamdata,$streamdata);

      foreach ($streamdata as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "url") {
          $value = urldecode($value);

               echo'<a class="button_video_more" href='.$value.' download="downloadfilename">Download Video</a>';
          } else {
            if ($key == "quality"){
                echo '<p class="itag_p_video">'.$ftmd[$value].'</p>';
            } 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar en tu pregunta un ejemplo del resultado esperado? ¿Tienes algún código donde nos muestres lo que has intentado?

Comment: listo ya puse el code @Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es imprimir la lista de vídeos en su distintas calidades, entonces intenta hacerlo así:

- Utiliza [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para leer el valor devuelto por `file_get_contents` (*Por que la URL devuelve un `JSON`*)
- En la posición `['request']['files']['progressive']` podes encontrar la lista de videos en sus distintas calidades.
- Cada vídeo tiene las siguientes propiedades:

  > "profile": 164,
  >    "width": 640,
  >   "mime": "video/mp4",
  >   "fps": 24,
  >   "url": "https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1513978008~acl=%2A%2F898492317.mp4%2A~hmac=d9da3bd3c1729be949b2416a11b14420be0ac6a8d9ef368b1e363ae9c851574a/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/4635/9/248179269/898492317.mp4",
  >   "cdn": "akamai_interconnect",
  >   "quality": "360p",
  >   "id": 898492317,
  >   "origin": "gcs",
  >   "height": 360

### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://player.vimeo.com/video/248179269/config?autopause=1&byline=0&collections=1&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CClipController.main&default_to_hd=1&outro=nothing&portrait=0&share=1&title=0&watch_trailer=0&s=fcf097765e5857464f33a60d7466087fe8104def_1514060835');
$info = json_decode($json, true);
$videos = $info['request']['files']['progressive'];

foreach ($videos as $video) {

    echo '<a class="button_video_more" href="'.$video['url'].'" download="downloadfilename">Download Video</a>';
    echo '<p class="itag_p_video">'.$video['quality'].'</p>';
} ?>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/yvte-c519)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo :D